# Speed up facet aggregation query - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, facet

**Document Format:**

```
{
    ...,
    tag: [
      { 
        name: 'weather',
        value: 'hot'
      },
      {
        name: 'special',
        value: 'transparent'
      }
    ],
    type: 'mansion'
}
```

**Facet Query:**

```
db.getCollection('houses').aggregate([
  { 
    '$facet':
        { tags: [
            { '$unwind': '$tag' },
            { '$sortByCount': '$tag' },
            { '$limit': 20 } 
          ],
          types: [ { '$sortByCount': '$type' } ],
          total: [ { '$count': 'count' } ]
        }
  } 
])
```

**Explain:**

```
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {},
                "fields" : {
                    "tag" : 1,
                    "type" : 1,
                    "_id" : 0
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "db.houses",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {},
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$facet" : {
                "tags" : [ 
                    {
                        "$unwind" : {
                            "path" : "$tag"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$tag",
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            },
                            "limit" : NumberLong(20)
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "types" : [ 
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : "$type",
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "sortKey" : {
                                "count" : -1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "total" : [ 
                    {
                        "$group" : {
                            "_id" : {
                                "$const" : null
                            },
                            "count" : {
                                "$sum" : {
                                    "$const" : 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$project" : {
                            "_id" : false,
                            "count" : true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

I have a collection `houses` with 1 million documents. I want to get counts of all kind of tags and types. But the query took ~25s for 1 million documents. It's so slow.

I created many indexes for tag and type but it didn't apply to this query. How can I make a faster facet query?

Comment: index wont help you here because you have no search condition . i see you use limit 20. if you put it at first in the pipeline it will make it fast (but you will have different results) if you rely need to do this action over 1 million documents then it will be slow

Comment: I used limit 20 for getting the top 20 tags. If index won't help, Is there any way to speed up facet query or this is a limitation of mongodb?

Comment: acutely  i think what takes the most time in this query is the unwind as it has to recreate all the object with new objects. unwind is good for small sets of data. in your case i think you need a different approach. you want to count by the tag name or value?

Comment: I tried counting type facet only, it's still so long ~15s. Could you show me a different approach for both cases: tag name and tag value. Thank you for your time @amit-wagner

Comment: in this case the best and fasts option you have is to keep the query as is and cache the results